# Split List based on range into multiple list :PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a small doubt , and i was not able to solve it , consider i have a list seperated with comma , and the data is dynamic may be 2 data or more than that

```
example : listVaue = ['Server1,Stop,Server2,START,.....,ServerN,StartN/StopN']
```

where N is a number

so if i have to split this into something like **[[Server1,Stop],[Server2,Start2],....[ServerN,StartN/StopN]]**

Is this possible . I wrote a code , but it is not working properly

```
listVaue = ['Server1,Stop,Server2,START']

c_index = listVaue.index("Stop")
l2 = listVaue[:c_index]

print(l2)
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem

Comment: `'Server1,Stop,Server2,START'` is a single string. This `['Server1','Stop','Server2','START']` is a list of strings.

Comment: why is `listVaue` a list when it contains only a single string and is supposed to work like a string. second,

Comment: So is there no way to do with the existing list @BlackThunder

Comment: @Jortega , even so . Is there no way to split it into two or N

Comment: `.split(',')` will split the string into a list, see the answer @Poorna Chandra R submistted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
listVaue = ['Server1,Command1,9182,Running,START,Server2,Command2,8888,Running,RESTART,ServerN,CommandN,N,Running,restart']
listVaue = listVaue[0].split(',')
a = ['START', 'RESTART', 'STOP', 'BOUNCE']
s = []
l2 = []
for i in listVaue:
    s.append(i)
    if i.upper() in a:
        l2.append(s)
        s = []
```

Comment: but ut is not only Stop , it can be start or Restart or bounce

Comment: can you give me the full list

Comment: ['Server1,Command1,9182,Running,START,Server2,Command2,8888,Running,RESTART,ServerN,CommandN,N,Running,restart]

Comment: and here the value of restart / start / stop will change , and what if there are many data

Comment: @AuroraEugene, Edited the answer. Check it once.

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal  :(

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.
see the List once the one you have sent me does not have a ' at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230754/discussion-between-aurora-eugene-and-poorna-chandra-r).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
listValue = ["server1, stop, server2, start"]
listValue = listValue[0].split(",")
l2 = [[first_item, second_item] for first_item, second_item in zip(listValue[0::2], listValue[1::2])]
```

Comment: Hi , this will work , if there is multiple string , in my case . i have only a single string

Comment: So what if i have something like ['ServerName1,Command1,...,Start,ServerNam2,Command2....,Stop,.....,ServerNameN,CommandN,......,Restart']

Comment: You could modify the indices and the step size for the slicing (list[start:stop:step]). If the server name occurs as 1st and then after every 5 items and start/stop occurs as the 3rd and then after every 5 items, you could specify for server names "listValue[0::5]" and for start/stop "listValue[2::5]". Can you assume that the position of server names and start/stop in the list follow some regular pattern?

Comment: that is giving me EOL

Comment: it is as u said , servername, and 5th position will be either start/stop or restart

Comment: regarding EOL (end of line error): have you put quotes at the start and the end of the string? If you sent me the code you are executing, it would be easier to help debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list defined as:

```
listVaue = ['Server1,Stop,Server2,START']
```

it actually only has one value, which is a string of value `'Server1,Stop,Server2,START'`. If you can define a different list, I would suggest trying to do:

```
listVaue = ['Server1', 'Stop', 'Server2', 'START']
```

or even a list of tuples, if you would like values to be correspondent:

```
listVaue = [('Server1', 'Stop'), ('Server2', 'START')]
```

Now, if you don't have control over the input data (and therefore cannot change the original list), what you can do is to first split all values by comma and then aggregate them 2 by 2.

```
# Original list
listVaue = ['Server1,Stop,Server2,START']
# Split string into separate values
# Take the first element - from your code it looks 
# like you only have a continuous string
new_list = listVaue[0].split(',')
# If you know that the list length will always be even, you can 
# aggregate them 2 by 2 using the following code:
l2 = [(new_list[i], new_list.pop(i + 1)) for i in range(len(new_list) // 2)]
l2
>>> [('Server1', 'Stop'), ('Server2', 'START')]
```

What the code does is basically to get elements in position `i` and the next one as well `(i + 1)`, removing the latter, whilst iterating through half the length of the list. Because you change its size as you iterate, always removing the second item, you'll end up only iterating through the original indexes 0, 2, 4, 6, 8..., whilst also retrieving their counterpart (1, 3, 5, 7, 9...).

Please note that changing the size of a list whilst you iterate is not generally a good practice, but because we are copying the original list, it shouldn't be a big problem for your case.

You can also change my code to whatever suits you, and you're probably better off with a normal for loop instead of a list comprehension:

```
listVaue = ['Server1,Stop,Server2,START']
new_list = listVaue[0].split(',')
l2 = []
for i in range(len(my_list) // 2):
   # Change square brackets to round ones if you want a tuple (immutable) instead
   l2.append([new_list[i], new_list.pop(i + 1)]
print(l2)
```